# CMS built on Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, content-management-system

Is there a CMS built on Zend Framework?
As alternative, are there classes that allow to easier implement a CMS with Zend Framework?

If there are any CMSs, can you suggest which one is better, or which one you would use?

Answer (score 6):

Although you've already accepted an answer: Give [pimcore](http://www.pimcore.org) a try. Based on the Zend Framework and the Zend MVC principle.

Comment: It's very hard to get any support for pimcore on SO. no one uses it!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't read it but there is a book on this: [Pro Zend Framework Techniques: Build a Full CMS Project](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430218797)

Comment: I have read the book, it's useful if you're new to ZF and you never ever created a CMS before, but don't expect to find a full blown CMS in the book.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing e-business with the CMS, then yes, the [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) is an ECommerce platform.

`NOTE: Magento is built in codeigniter.  Look at http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/ellislab-seeking-new-owner-for-codeigniter`

Comment: Magento is not built on CodeIgniter. First version was on Zend Framework 1 (some components).

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [SingularCore](http://www.singularcore.com/) as basis. Authors of this CMF are going to release fully-featured CMS based on Singular Core next year.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [upcoming XOOPS version](http://xoops.org/modules/news/article.php?storyid=5782).