# CMS plugin for Zend Website

Tags: php, zend-framework, content-management-system

Am looking for some advice.
i have a website built using Zend Framework and i need to implement a CMS as part of the site.
Before i go off reinventing the wheel, I am just wondering if there is any open source CMS plugin that can be used with the Zend Framework - like a Joomla plugin that can be configured to give basic CMS functionality which can be incorporated into my site???

Have searched around and come across various open source CMS but have not yet found a CMS that can be incorportated into a site built with Zend.

Many thanks
S

Comment: I don't believe there is anything like that at the moment. You will have to write your own. I am working on a Zend CMS skeleton (a simple automated content management based on database schema) in my free time for my own purposes but it will take me some time to finish it.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Maybe there is a CMS plugin that I could use that can be incorporated as part of the site. The CMS doesn't have to plugin to the Zend framework, just become part of the site.

Answer (score 0):

You may use one of [Zend framework based CMS](http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=%22zend+framework+based+cms%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) solutions, e.g. [Tomato CMS](http://tomatocms.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like these. [CMS built on Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925735/cms-built-on-zend-framework)

http://sourceforge.net/search/?q=zend&q=zend+cms