# Is there any CMS/CMF built on Zend Framework 2 yet?

Tags: php, content-management-system, zend-framework2

I have worked a little in the past on Zend Framework, and now I have to do it again, and since there's a new release of Zend Framework 2, I was wondering what would boost my new project.
So I have some questions like:

- **Is it better to start with Zend Framework 2?**
- **Is it better to start with a CMS/CMF based on Zend Framework?** (to boost the project startup process)
- **If so, what are the CMS/CMF based on (or willing to upgrade to) Zend Framework 2?**

PS: throughout my research I have found and categorized some CMS/CMF based on Zend:

- Famous but relatively old (probably abandoned, I'm not sure)

  - **TomatoCMS** (my favorite of this category, uses jQuery)
  - Digitalus CMS
  - PimCore
- Newer (probably still active)

  - ZF-Boilerplate (currently working on a version for Zend Framework 2)
  - **Centurion** (my favorite of this category, uses jQuery, CRUD and supports social identification. I might be leaning a little towards it)

Finally, I probably mention that my project goes under the CMS category and considered mid-sized.

Waiting your opinions, especially if anyone has already worked with TomatoCMS, Centurion or Zend Framework 2.

**Updated:**

I know that there's a related question "[CMS built on Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925735/cms-built-on-zend-framework)" but it does not answer all of my questions.

Comment: Another Current, relevant and useful question closed by the stackoverflow moderators as "not constructive" - Hope everyone voted well this year....

Comment: If it helps, I ended up using Centurion CMS, and it did boost up the project. But it wasn't like I hoped in terms of documentation or code optimization, and no major updates ever released since. The final line, I was pleased with my choice and surprised not to see any other opensource projects based on ZF.

Answer (score 6):

Of course it is worth starting with Zend Framework 2.0 *if You are doing a new project* cause eventually the code will be cleaner and many new used features will make your development easier.

As far as I  know, there aren't yet any known CMS, which has moved to ZF2 or a CMS, that has been built from zero - after all only 3 weeks have passed since the release of the stable.

Usually the cost of *upgrading* >=middle-sized applications from ZF1 to ZF2 is too big, as the logic is quite different.

Although some [tests](http://www.enrise.com/2012/02/zend-framework-2-performance/) show that ZF2 responds 4 times slower than ZF1, eventually after some optimizations and updates, I am sure it will become even better, so its a good investment to start with ZF2.

Comment: Thanks @Jevgeni, after all, I found that all current so called CMS based on ZF1 are old, buggy, not complete and shouldn't be called CMS in the first place.. and you are right about ZF2 it's still fresh and the upgrade cost is big..

Comment: It's really strange to find such big fuss around zend framework with no really good projects built on it..